# Calculating day-of-week in years greater than 9999

Tags: algorithm, datetime

I was wondering if there are any algorithms that calculate the day of week in years that are greater than the year 9999.

Algorithms such [Zeller’s algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeller%27s_congruence) or this one [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculating_the_day_of_the_week) gives false results, since they handle only 4 digit year.

Thank you.

Comment: +1 for early preparation for Y10K!

Comment: Hopefully a better algorithm will be invented by then

Comment: and we can be sure that Easter will fall on a Sunday. Really, if you expect a sensible answer to an apparently ridiculous question, you should explain why you are asking it

Comment: If the Earth continues to get farther from the Sun as its present speed and its rotation continues to diminish likewise, how long will a day be in 8000 years and how cold will it be at the Equator?

Comment: maybe you too need to explain why you post such a "ridiculous" comment?

Comment: martani: you don't need to worry about weekdays in 8000 years. In some countries (according to wikipedia) weeks began to have 7 days less than 100 years ago!

Comment: @pmg actually I need this for a simple math games we are doing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't actually need a new algorithm. As long as you have *one* algorithm with a range of 400 years (or more), you can bring any date inside the range of that algorithm. This works because the Gregorian calendar repeats every 400 years (XX/YY/ZZZZ is the same weekday as XX/YY/(ZZZZ+400)).

So, if we assume that you have some algorithm that works for the dates 1/1/1600 to 31/12/1999 (both inclusive), you can calculate the weekday for any date by using `(year mod 400)+1600` as the year.

If you don't have a 400-year range starting on 1/1/XXXX (where `XXXX mod 400 = 0`), you need to manipulate the date slightly different to get the right result (instead of adding 1600 to the year, add X*400, where X is an integer such that some of the dates will be in the range, then add or subtract 400 to the year for those dates that are outside of the range).

Answer (score 1):

http://lxr.linux.no/linux/net/netfilter/xt_time.c for example simply counts it out. To reduce the number of iterations in loops, static tables may be used, as has been done there.